# How can I make a function with edited type?

Tags: function, ocaml

```
type exp =
  X
| INT of int
| ADD of exp * exp
| SUB of exp * exp
| MUL of exp * exp
| DIV of exp * exp
| SIGMA of exp * exp * exp

let rec calculator : exp -> int
  = fun e -> match e with
   | INT a -> a
   | ADD (a, b) -> calculator a + calculator b
   | SUB (a, b) -> calculator a - calculator b
   | MUL (a, b) -> calculator a * calculator b
   | DIV (a, b) ->  calculator a / calculator b
   | SIGMA (a, b, c) ->  if a>b then 0 else (c a) + SIGMA( (a+1) ,b ,c)
```

at this moment, with (c a), i got an error message

> Error: This expression has type exp
>          This is not a function; it cannot be applied.

How can i correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message seems pretty clear. The variable `c` represents something of type `exp`, which isn't a function. So you can't just call it to get a result. On the other hand, you are writing a function that figures out the value of something of type `exp`. So the thing to do would probably be to call your function (recursively) to figure out the value of `c`.

This is complicated by the fact that (as far as I can figure out) you want the value of `X` to be different at different times. It seems you need to do some work to keep track of the current value of `X` during a call to the `calculator` function.

Comment: thx for answering, how ever i edited like SIGMA(a,b,c) -> let rec sigma (a,b,c) = if a>b then 0 else (c a) +sigma(a+1,b,c).. but it didn't track the current value of calculator function....